# Best practices for managing changes to files within a script

Tags: bash, workflow

I have a BASH script which performs many actions on a file, for e.g.:

```
cp input.txt file.tmp1
sed (code) file.tmp1 > file.tmp2
sed (code) file.tmp2 > file.tmp3
sed (code) file.tmp3 > file.tmp4
sed (code) file.tmp4 > file.tmp5
sed (code) file.tmp5 > file.tmp6
sed (code) file.tmp6 > file.tmp7
cp output.txt
```

In this way:

- The original file is unchanged.
- I can check the files changes at each stage, just to make sure my code did not do anything wrong.

However, this seems a not very ideal way to handle the files.

- Is there a better way to do this?
- Is there any tool which can help inspect the changes, just to see if anything unusual was introduced?

Comment: it might sounds over kill but version controlling tools (git, svn) should work better ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working on a temporary file is a fine idea, but you should use `mktemp(1)` to make your temporary file safely.

While there's nothing wrong with using multiple files for multiple passes, consider using `mktemp -d` to create a temporary directory for all your files to ensure you never overwrite anything the user cares about.

But if you're never going to look at the intermediate files, multiple passes can be handled like this:

```
sed (code) input.txt | sed (code) | sed (code) | sed (code) | ...
    sed (code) > output.txt
```

If one fails, they all fail, which can make for easier error handling. There's no temporary files to remove when you're finished.

If you like to inspect the pipelines for errors, `tee` will help you. It redirects all input both to its standard output and a pipe, used like:

```
sed (code) input.txt | sed (code) | tee state-of-pipe.txt | sed (code) | ...
    sed (code) > output.txt
```

You can inspect the changes by using `diff -u input.txt output.txt`. `diff(1)` is a line-wise differences program, and the `-u` unified output is pretty easy to read. `wdiff(1)` is a word-wise differences program, which might be more useful for some cases.

And `xxdiff(1)` is a superb GUI interface for inspecting the differences between two files -- it will go to some effort to show you individually changed characters. (It is also fantastic for handling CVS- and SVN-style conflict files, but that's another matter completely.)

Comment: +1. Just as a little side-note: `tee` is a great tool to inspect pipelines for errors, and if you don't mind, I'd expand your answer with it.

Comment: @thiton: please do! Another option is to steal my line for your own answer and improve it, so you can get some +1 on it :)

Answer (score 1):

A more effective way would be to use pipes. E.g.:

```
cat input.txt | sed ... | ... | sed ... > output.txt
```

The problem is that you can not check the changes of the different stages.